# IComparer not sorting properly

Tags: c#, .net, list, collections, comparison

I am currently working on a project where I need to sort entries of a list of tuples according to a certain scheme.
For that purpose I wrote a simple IComparer:

```
private class OrderComparer : IComparer<Tuple<string, DateTime, string>>
{
    public int Compare(Tuple<string, DateTime, string> x, Tuple<string, DateTime, string> y)
    {
        var yearX = x.Item1.Substring(x.Item1.Length - 2);
        var yearY = y.Item1.Substring(y.Item1.Length - 2);
        var monthX = x.Item1.Substring(x.Item1.Length - 4, 2);
        var monthY = y.Item1.Substring(y.Item1.Length - 4, 2);
        var numberX = x.Item1.Substring(1, x.Item1.Length - 5);
        var numberY = y.Item1.Substring(1, y.Item1.Length - 5);


        if (!yearX.Equals(yearY))
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(yearX).CompareTo(Convert.ToInt32(yearY));
        }
        if (!monthX.Equals(monthY))
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(monthX).CompareTo(Convert.ToInt32(monthY));
        }
        return Convert.ToInt32(numberX).CompareTo(Convert.ToInt32(numberY));
    }
}
```

the reading of yearX/Y, monthX/Y and numberX/Y works correctly as found in a debugging session.

The problem I am now facing is that it sorts correctly after the year and month but not the number.
I verified, that

```
return Convert.ToInt32(numberX).CompareTo(Convert.ToInt32(numberY));
```

returns the correct value (1 when numberX > numberY).

I call the sort method using the following code:

```
var dataList = data as IList<Tuple<string, DateTime, string>> ?? data.ToList();
dataList.ToList().Sort(new OrderComparer());
```

where data is an IEnumerable.

I am sorry for this rather simple question but I am completely stuck and I don't see any error in my implementation.
Kind regards

Lukas
EDIT: since sample data is needed. Here's the data the algorithm fails:
B080114,
B140114,
B100114,
B160114,
B130114

this is the actual result after sorting

Comment: Instead of using a complicated sorting operation based on `String`s, why not parse it to a `DateTime` first, this will probably improve speed as well... `DateTime` has a builtin comparable. Sou you can then sort without implementing a comparable yourself.

Comment: Can you give some sample data that it is failing on (something we can just copy and paste to reproduce your problem)?

Comment: Having just made up some test data it seems to work for me... My test data had irrelevant data in parts two and three of the tuple and in the first part had strings `{"010114", "020114", "010214", "020314", "010113", "010213", "020113"}`. Your comparer correctly sorted by 5th and 6th digit (year), 3rd and 4th digit (month) and 2nd digit (number). This means there is somethign you are not showing or explaining correctly. For example is number meant to just be the second digit of the string?

Comment: @CommuSoft sadly this is not possible because the number can go way beyond 31 and DateTime only allows valid days

Comment: @Chris I added sample data

Comment: @LukasHäfliger: Cheers. Its good to be able to see the right data so that I can be sure testing is on the right stuff rather than my assumed data structure being a problem. Good news is I've now replicated your problem and got a fix for you (see below). This is why its always good to put everything needed to replicate a problem in answers where possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
dataList.ToList().Sort(new OrderComparer())
```

the `Sort` method as you know doesn't return the sorted version but operates on the original list. Here however the list it is sorting is not `dataList` but `dataList.ToList()` which is not the same item.

So it sorts `dataList.ToList()` in place but since you have no reference to it it is thrown away and you are left with the unmodified `dataList` instead.

The best fix would probably be to change the preceding line to:

```
var dataList = data.ToList();
```

So rather than checking if it is a suitable `IList` and so on we are just doing a `ToList()` to make sure we have a List so the next line can then be:

```
dataList.Sort(new OrderComparer());
```

This will now work on the correct list and hopefully thus do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to guess what the problem is since you don't provide sample data.

I assume you should replace

```
var numberX = x.Item1.Substring(1, x.Item1.Length - 5);
```

with:

```
var numberX = x.Item1.Substring(0, x.Item1.Length - 6);
```

(don't forget to modify the line for `numberY` as well).
Since strings start with index `0` (and you probably only grab the last digit).

Although I would advice you to simply parse the `string` to a `DateTime` object (there is a builtin method for this, that will probably suffice), and then use the default comparable of the `DateTime` object. This will improve speed as well since this method will parse `string` objects on average O(n log n) times [and worst case O(n^2) times] instead of O(n) times

Comment: We don't know that the string is a DateTime so that might be foolish. The fact it is year, month and number rather than year/month/day suggests that it is not a date. I assume the number is an auto-incremented number of some kind that is reset each month. And whether the first part is right or not is entirely for the OP to know. It could for example be a code like `X10314` where X is not needed for sorting. Hopefully the OP will get back to us with info on the data he is sorting though...

Comment: True that, as long as the TS does not provide some sample data, we can only guess the true format. although in that case one could use a tuple `Tuple<DateTime,int>` where DataTime is set to the first day of each month. It will simplify the comparing anyhow.